# not able to run java code in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

in java its working...but in jsp page its..
not able to create file in JSP...

**in plain JAVA: A.java**

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String x = "name,age";
        Connection connection = null; 
        try { // Load the JDBC driver 
         String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; Class.forName(driverName);

        // Create a connection to the database
        String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
        String portNumber = "1521";
        String sid = "XE";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
        String username = "system";
        String password = "system";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\AACB.csv");
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
                pw.println(x);        

                Statement s = connection.createStatement();
                String query = "select "+x+" from dummytable";
                ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);

                while(rs.next())
                {         
                    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(x,",");


            while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(stk.nextToken()));
                }
            }
            pw.flush();

            //Close the Print Writer
            pw.close();

            //Close the File Writer
            fw.close();
            s.close();
    connection.close();       
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

}
}

in this i m just selecting the chkbox and sending the data to operation.jsp page.. and trying to make csv file...
in plain java(above A.java code) its working but in jsp its not..

in jsp: index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<body>
<FORM method="POST" ACTION="operation.jsp">
<center>
Select Fields: <br><br>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=fields VALUE=name>
    </td>   
    <td>   
        name
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=fields VALUE=age>
    </td>   
    <td>   
        age
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input TYPE=checkbox name=fields VALUE=address>
    </td>   

    <td>   
        address
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
<br> <INPUT TYPE=submit name=submit Value="Submit">
</center>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

operation.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.StringTokenizer"%>
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%! String[] fields; %>
<%! String x ; %>
<center>You have selected: 
<% 
   fields = request.getParameterValues("fields");
   x = fields[0];
   if (fields != null) 
   {
      for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) 
      {
          x += ", " + fields[i];          
      }
   }
   else out.println ("<b>none<b>");

   out.println(x);
%>

<% 
Connection connection = null; 
try { // Load the JDBC driver 
 String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"; Class.forName(driverName);

// Create a connection to the database
String serverName = "127.0.0.1";
String portNumber = "1521";
String sid = "XE";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
String username = "system";
String password = "system";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\abckjk.csv");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.println(x);        

        Statement s = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "select "+ x +" from dummytable";
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next())
        {   

            StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(x,",");
                    while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
                        pw.print(rs.getString(stk.nextToken()));
                        pw.print(",");
                    }
            pw.println();
        }
        pw.flush();

        //Close the Print Writer
        pw.close();

        //Close the File Writer
        fw.close();
        s.close();
connection.close();
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { // Could not find the database driver 
} catch (SQLException e) 
{ // Could not connect to the database } 

}

%>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a little bit more details would be nice... environment, exception or what actually is not working

Comment: Why are you putting this much code in jsp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way;

```
   String nameOfFile = "D:\\abckjk.csv";
   try {   
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(nameOfFile));
      pw.println(str);
      //clean up
      pw.close();
   } catch(IOException e) {
      out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
```

But too much java code in jsp page is not recommended.